# How i can have one horizontal scroll bar that work for multiple horizontal galleries that are inside one vertical gallery

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a Vertical gallery which contain many Horizontal galleries as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1703715668971.png]

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1703715705521.png]

here are the end result:-

[image]

now for each horizontal gallery i have a separate horizontal scroll bar , so is there a way to have one horizontal scroll bar that will move all the horizontal galleries as we scroll through it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to have one horizontal scroll bar that works for multiple horizontal galleries inside a vertical gallery. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Scroll-multiple-galleries-at-once/td-p/931309

Put all the galleries inside a scrollable canvas datacard. To get a scrollable canvas, add a scrollable screen and copy the canvas component from it.
Set the scrollable canvas height to the size you want the scroll bar to be.
Set the datacard height to the height of the tallest gallery.

Comment: did you try it , as it did not work for me